# Website developing and linking to email addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I'm developing a website in Serif WebPlus X8 and have included a 'Branch Locator'.

Serif doesn't do this so I have had to include additional code based on a .xml file. The results can be seen at www.mwphillipschemists.co.uk.

My problem is that the email links in the info boxes on the google map don't work.

Currently I have

```
<a href="email">{{email}}</a>
```

which puts the address in the box but throws an error 404 when the user clicks on the link.

The full code for the box contents is:

```
{{#location}}
<div class="loc-name">{{name}}</div>
<div>{{address}}</div>
<div>{{address2}}</div>
<div>{{town}}{{#if town}},{{/if}} {{county}} {{postal}}</div>
<div>{{hours1}}</div>
<div>{{hours2}}</div>
<div>{{hours3}}</div>
<div>{{phone}}</div>
<a href="email">{{email}}</a>
<div><a href="{{web}}" target="_blank">{{niceURL web}}</a></div>
{{/location}}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use a `mailto:person@company.com` as the `href` on those links vs. hitting that `/email` route. I can't tell from your question because of the formatting, but looking at the site it seems like that's what you want to do.